# Submit form without redirection with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to make some things with ajax and it doesn't work.

I have a view with some divs where i will be all the functionality of the page.

The view's code is this:

```
@extends('cms.public.layouts.default')
@section('content')

<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3 style="letter-spacing:40px;text-align:center;color:f15d5e;">PROYECTOS</h3>
</div>

<div id="listall"> <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS START HERE -->
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:20px;">
          <button type="button" id="buttoncreate" class="btn btn-danger">Crear Proyecto</button>

        </div>
                      <table class="table">
                  <thead style="color:white">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Slug</th>
                      <th>Order</th>
                      <th>Public</th>
                      <th>Path header</th>
                      <th>Path home</th>
                      <th>Fecha creación</th>
                      <th>Fecha ultima actualización</th>
                      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr>
                      <th>{{$project->id}}</th>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->pathheader}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->pathhome}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->created_at))}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->updated_at))}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  @endforeach
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
  <br><br>
</div>  <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS END HERE -->

<div id="form1" style="display:none;" class="col-md-8"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->
    <div>
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>



    <div id="formcreateproject">

        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" name="myForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
</div> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 END HERE-->

<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-">
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>
</div>

</div>
@stop
```

And the javascript function is this:

```
//Javascript view /projects/menu.blade.php
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#buttoncreate").click(function(){
        $("#listall").hide();
        $("#form1").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#createprojectsubmit").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
                type:'post',
                data:$('#myForm'),
                success: function(){
                    $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                   $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });
      });
});
```

The function of hide the first div and fade in the second works, and it submit and create the new project. But url change and show me a white page.

My first thing to do is fadeOut the form1 and fadein the second form. It will be great, if when fadeOut the form1, in her space appears a tick/check.

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is because the `submit` function as you call it, is only makes the binding on the `submit` event not executing anything...

Comment: So when use submit function, only makes the 'submit'? If you put anything more will not be executed? @ADreNaLiNe-DJ anyway if i change to click doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer ;o)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `submit` event on button which does not belong to button. It belongs to form. So call the `click` event on button and use `preventDefault()` to stop the form to be submitted as

```
$("#createprojectsubmit").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your further code goes here
}
```

use like this

```
$("#createprojectsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your further code goes here
}
```

You can also trigger the `submit` event on your `form` as

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your further code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hi @RAUSHANKUMAR doesn't work your code. Form don't make the submit :l

Comment: you have two form, and each form you have same id for submit button, give unique id to them and your form also, then try

Comment: I know mate, it's just hardcoded this is why have same id, etc. Anyway, the first form is will i try to submit and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are mixing 2 ways to handle the submission of your form: the click on the button and the form submission itself.

The function `submit` as you call in your script is making the binding of the `submit` event when the button is clicked.

Here is how to bind your code only on the `submit` event of your `form`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttoncreate").click(function(){
        $("#listall").hide();
        $("#form1").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#myForm'),
            success: function(){
                $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Edited answer to take in account the click on the button.

At first, we bind the  `click` event on the `button` to handle `animations` and trigger the form submission by calling `submit` function on the form.

Then, we bind the `submit` event on the `form` to handle the `ajax` call in replacement of the `classic postback` form submission.

Comment: Thanks for comment @ADreNaLiNe-DJ i'm trying to understand what do you want to do. How this code do to fadeout the div listall when click to the button with id=buttoncreate ? In your code you have $("#myForm") but this is only the id of the of the form method, not the button. Anyway, now, form doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood some things. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Mmm.. I think i understand it, it give me an 'error', this: TokenMismatchException maybe we forgot something about the Token. Know what? @ADreNaLiNe-DJ thanks a lot!